# Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes in simulation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, simulation, tensor

When I run the following code, I got the error

`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9999,10000) (10000,10000) (9999,10000)` 
I think it is about the way I define `grid_spacing = wavelength /2  # meters` . I tried different values but still the same problem.

Here is my complete code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define simulation parameters
wavelength = 1e-3   # meters
aperture_diameter = 0.5   # meters
screen_distance = 5   # meters
grid_spacing = wavelength /2  # meters
num_points = int(screen_distance / grid_spacing)
time_step = grid_spacing / (2 * np.sqrt(2))   # seconds
num_time_steps = int(screen_distance / (wavelength * time_step))

# Define aperture function
def aperture(x, y):
    r = np.sqrt(x*2 + y*2)
    if r <= aperture_diameter / 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

# Initialize electric field array
E = np.zeros((num_points, num_points), dtype=np.complex128)

# Main simulation loop
for t in range(num_time_steps):
    # Update magnetic field
    Hx = np.diff(E, axis=0) / grid_spacing
    Hy = np.diff(E, axis=1) / grid_spacing
    Hx = np.pad(Hx, ((0, 1), (0, 0)), mode='constant')
    Hy = np.pad(Hy, ((0, 0), (0, 1)), mode='constant')
    
    # Update electric field
    E[:-1,:] -= time_step * Hx
    E[:,:-1] += time_step * Hy
    
    # Apply aperture function
    x = np.linspace(-screen_distance/2, screen_distance/2, num_points)
    y = np.linspace(-screen_distance/2, screen_distance/2, num_points)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')
    aper = aperture(xx, yy)
    E *= aper
    
# Calculate intensity at screen
I = np.abs(E)**2

# Plot results
plt.imshow(I, cmap='gray', extent=[-screen_distance/2, screen_distance/2, -screen_distance/2, screen_distance/2])
plt.xlabel('Position (m)')
plt.ylabel('Position (m)')
plt.title('Diffraction pattern for circular aperture')
plt.show()
```

I can not reduce the value of `grid_spacing` so much, because I don't have enough ram neither.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Cause you already do the `pad` for `Hx` and `Hy`, When you update electric field, no need to slice the last row or column for `E` .

Comment: Could you please give me more explanation? Shall I simply remove this part?

Comment: Change to `E -= time_step * Hx` and `E += time_step * Hy`